# docker bitnami/laravel se detiene solo

Tags: laravel, docker

quiero tener una imagen de laravel con docker, y he visto que en dockerhub está esta : https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel/ .

```
docker run -td bitnami/laravel
```

entonces hago rapidamente un `docker ps` y se ve el proceso del container. Pero al cabo de unos segundos se cierra, me voy a `docker ps -a` y ahi esta, detenido.

No tiene sentido no? Si yo ejecuto ese contenedor y lo abro deberia de quedar puesto en background. Yo quiero que se quede abierto siempre, de hecho es lo esperado.
Tambien he probado con `-d` y tal, pero acaba borrandose.

Comment: Si usas docker logs te muestra algo? No usas docker-compose por? Este tipo de información debería de estar en la pregunta de base

Comment: @ICIM no, me pone de logs las cosas que hace al tirar el run por primera vez, docker-compose ? no se que hace eso

Comment: Ok... en el link que dejaste en tu pregunta tienes un punto llamado **Local workspace** haz los comandos que te marca allí. Docker-compose es una forma de tener en un fichero tus dockers, te recomiendo esto, se te va hacer muy fácil de trabajar con docker. En el logs te dirá el motivo por el que no se mantiene encendido